# How can I get YAML::load to call const_missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, activerecord, yaml

I am serializing an object to a database field using ActiveRecord's :serialize functionality in Ruby on Rails

```
class DrawElement < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    serialize :content

end
```

The reason I'm serializing the objects is that I'm dynamically loading the types from disk using const_missing, so I don't have to setup database tables for them.

```
def DrawElement.const_missing(const)
    require File.join('draw_elements',const.to_s)
    draw_class = const_get(const)
    return draw_class if draw_class
    raise "Draw Element not found #{const.to_s}"
end
```

So when I want to add a draw element, I do something like this in `irb`

```
draw_element.content = DrawElement::Text.new
```

Everything here works fine

The problem is that when I try to load the object from the database in a fresh session, `YAML::load` never calls `const_missing` to require the class definition before loading the file.  So all my `@content` objects come back as `YAML::Object`

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm trying to be able to add new types without having to change the database, or have a `has_many_polymorph` relationship between DrawElements and a Document.

Ruby on Rails v.2.3.8, Ruby v. 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience [`YAML::load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/YAML.html#M006007) returns a hash. It's up to me to walk through the hash and do something with its contents. Neither `load` or [`load_file`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/YAML.html#M006008) accept a block to get inside them and influence how the YAML document is parsed.

You could try messing with [`load_documents`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/YAML.html#M006012) or [`each_document`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/YAML.html#M006011) though, because they take a block, but I don't know if you could add additional hash elements that way.